# Getting partition list of inserted df partitions

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Is there a way to get the file list or partition name of the partition that was inserted into the table?

```
df.write.format("parquet").partitionBy('id,name').insertInto(...)
```

A sample of the following command I wish to get a list :

```
1,Jhon
2,Jake
3,Dain
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think thats possible because to don't what was already present in the table and what was newely added.

Of course you can query your dataframe to get this:

```
val partitionList = df.select($"id,name").distinct.map(_.getString(0)).collect
```